# Visual Studio Code. Disable GitLens panel on tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

[panel on tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX11J.png)

How to remove this panel?
It is panel from extansion GitLens. But im not found settings to disable this!

Answer (score 8):

I had to add this to my `settings.json` file:

```
"gitlens.menus": {
    "editorGroup": {
        "blame": false,
        "compare": false
    }
},
```

Credit goes to [ronjouch](https://github.com/Axosoft/vscode-gitlens/issues/669#issuecomment-467539945).

Answer (score 5):

Open GitLense Settings -> find "Add commands to the editor group toolbar" -> uncheck -> restart VSCode

Comment: Was this renamed recently? I can't find this option at all in the gitlens settings.